# Replacements for Resharper's Alt+Enter to include a reference in your code or xaml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I always used Resharper and liked to function to press Alt+Enter and Resharper would include my required dll in my code file or namespace in my Xaml.

Now i'm not allowed anymore to use Resharper due to performance issues in VB.net so i'm looking for a replacement tool for this functionality.

I don't need all the other extra's from resharper but this is something very usefull to me.

Comment: Are you already beyond investigating performance issues? I.e. disable solution wide analysis.

Comment: the issues are not mine, just company policy. So i'm looking for any free tool ;)

Comment: Company policy not to use ReSharper? I don't know what's the company, but really? `.NET` also can be prohibited due to performance reasons with this logic...

Comment: yes really, license cost + performance issues with vb.net due to poor laptops

Answer (score 1):

One alternative product is [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) which may perform better than ReSharper. I can't say for sure as I've never used it.

Without wanting to sound flippant though, would you not be better off attempting to fix the performance issue by upgrading your computer hardware or reinstalling Windows for example?